# Отправить пёрышко в полёт по́ ветру или по ве́тру?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

*Отправил пёрышко в полёт по́ ветру.* Или *по ве́тру*?
Где правильное ударение?

Answer (score 2):

Комментарий к ответу oleedd

1. По́ ветру — ударение обстоятельства.

Это абсолютно верно. Смещение ударение  на предлог очень важно. Существительное (с предметным значением) отодвигается в сторону, становится клитиком (присоединяется к предлогу) и  в сочетании «пустить по́ ветру» дополнением  уже быть не может.

Вспомним определение:
Дополнение — это второстепенный член предложения, называющий лицо, ПРЕДМЕТ или явление, на который распространяется ДЕЙСТВИЕ или по отношению к которому проявляется признак.

Нет самостоятельного предмета – нет и дополнения.

2. По ве́тру — ударение дополнения.
   Это действительно дополнение,  а падежная форма отвечает на вопрос (в направлении чего?)  – в направлении ветра.  Обстоятельственный вопрос (как?) тоже можно задать, но при этом нужно дополнительно СМЕСТИТЬ ударение на предлог (вот в чем фишка).
3. Как же сделать выбор? Нужно учитывать семантику и глагола, и всего сообщения.

Если мы хотим определить  направление  ветра (чтобы предсказать погоду по ветру), то перышко пригодится. Тогда пускаем его по ве́тру (дополнение).

Пример: Белые чайки издали казались кусочками белой бумаги, которые шаловливая рука пустила по ве́тру.

Но если  мы просто хотим от него избавиться, то его можно или куда-нибудь выбросить, или пустить по́ ветру (обстоятельство).

Примеры: Успел пустить по́ ветру или что-то осталось ещё от тех денег?Тем более что зять её уже был разорён, пустив по́ ветру лавку своего отца.

Обстоятельство — это второстепенный член предложения, который относится к слову со значением действия или признака и обозначает качественные и количественные характеристики этого действия или признака (способ осуществления действия…и т.д.).

Все сходится,  форма по́ ветру  относится к глаголу и обозначает способ осуществления действия. Отметим также, что этот вариант используется чаще и обычно имеет переносное значение — растратить зря.

Comment: А в "*Он шёл по газону*"? Eagle утверждает, что здесь обстоятельство.

Comment: Скорее всего, он прав. В данном случае предмет обозначает МЕСТО, где ходить нельзя.  И это естественный вопрос:  ты где идешь? Вы же не скажете: по чему ты идешь?

Comment: Скажу))) Например: *Йог ходит по битому стеклу.* Тоже *где ходит?*

Comment: А здесь дополнение, так как важен сам ПРЕДМЕТ.  Нет единственного решения на все случаи жизни, также доверяйте естественным вопросам. Да и объяснение вполне убедительное, соответствует определению. В таких спорах грамматика очень даже помогает.

Comment: Вот. А в придуманном мной примере смысл в том, что ходит, скажем так, по предмету и портит его. Смысл не в месте. Газон, в отличие от огорода, означает лишь траву, а не территорию (место) — говорят "высадить газон", а не "высадить траву на газоне". Поэтому вопрос *где?* у меня не звучит.

Comment: Одна и та же форма (на траве) может быть и дополнением, и обстоятельством. Не сиди на траве, здесь сыро (где?) . Мне нравится сидеть на траве (на чем?).  Язык сам всё регулирует и подсказывает, надо больше ему доверять и внимательно слушать.  В каждой ситуации своя конкретика, а правило одно:  или предмет важен сам по себе, или он обозначает место.  Реже оба вопроса подходят, тогда у нас обстоятельственное дополнение.

Comment: Там Eagle комментарий добавил. Он прав? У меня в ответе некорректный пример?

Comment: А что же с "Тут будет трудно что-либо определить по ветру."? Вкладывал сюда смысл "по какому фактору?", а не "каким образом?".

Comment: Я думаю, что это (с учетом ударения)  или (1) собственно дополнение, или (2) дополнение с добавочным обстоятельственным значением. Все зависит от конкретной ситуации.   Например: (1) Надо учитывать ветер. – Разве погоду можно определить (по чему?) по ветру? (2) Как можно определить погоду? – Есть разные способы, в частности (как?) по ветру.

Comment: Тогда у меня корректный пример, а Eagle упёрся в обстоятельство и путает меня. Кстати, в словаре Ефремовой указано два ударения для обстоятельства. Тут можно сделать вывод, что ударение на предлоге народное, что связано с желанием соединить два слова в одно, а на существительном — стандартное.

Comment: Не совсем так, но отчасти верно.  Смещение ударения на предлог характерно для народной речи, и тогда между вариантами будет разница в стиле. Но в данном сочетании перенос ударения определяется не стилем, а переносным (образным) значением – «зря, напрасно». Образность присуща и народной речи, в этом можно увидеть сходство.

Comment: Да, это тоже заметил, уже после отправки комментария. А в других случаях (как в примере из вопроса), получается, возможны два варианта.

Comment: Перышко можно выбросить, образно говоря "пустить  по́ ветру".  Но скорее это делается для каких-то целей (для развлечения, например), и тогда надо использовать дополнение  по ве́тру.

Comment: Не думаю, что лишь с переносным значением такое ударение. Что ещё интересно, так это то, что если задавать вопрос от глагола (*отправил каким образом? как?*), то будет обстоятельство, а если "в полёт по чему?" (цельное сочетание: *полёт по ветру*), то будет дополнение. А ведь глагол-то дальше всего.

Comment: Полет по ветру - это уже другая история.  Выбирайте или обстоятельственное определение, или дополнение, но ударение вряд ли будет переноситься.

Answer (score 1):

*По́ ветру* — ударение обстоятельства. Так люди говорят. В данном примере это обстоятельство (вопрос *как?*), и это ударение уместно.

*По ве́тру* — ударение дополнения:
*Тут будет трудно что-либо определить по ветру.*

Похожий случай: *по полю* (в народных песнях).

В словаре Ефремовой указаны два ударения:
*п`о ветру, по в`етру*
В направлении движения потока воздуха.

Comment: *Тут будет трудно что-либо определить по ветру.* Тут «по ветру» тоже обстоятельство.

Comment: Вопрос *по чему?* тоже подходит. Ключевое здесь: **ударение** дополнения (как и в *по газону, по столу*), а не то, что это исключительно дополнение (это не было указано).

Comment: Тут вопрос: *каким образом?* Сказуемое «отправил». Отправил *что?* «пёрышко». «Пёрышко» — дополнение. Отправил *каким образом?* «по ветру». «По ветру» — обстоятельство образа действия.

Comment: Это да, но мы говорили о другом.

Comment: «Тут будет трудно что-либо определить по ветру». Но ведь «что-либо» —дополнение, а «по ветру» опять же обстоятельство образа действия. Определить *каким образом?* по ветру. Я не понимаю вашу мысль. В обоих случаях «по ветру» это обстоятельство, а не дополнение.

Comment: Тогда в *Он шёл (каким образом?) по газону.* тоже обстоятельство. *Каким образом?* почти везде подставляется. Порой подходят оба вопроса и оно может быть как обстоятельством, так и дополнением. Мне в моём примере ближе вопросы *по чему? по какому аспекту?* Мысль в том, что ударения в разных случаях разные.

Comment: Он шёл (где?) по газону. Это обстоятельство. _Дополнение обозначает предмет или лицо, являющееся объектом действия, выраженного сказуемым._ [[Виктпедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81))]

Comment: *Ударил по столу* тоже? *Он шёл (по чему?) по газону. Где?* — это более общий вопрос. Вы интерпретируете существительные в предложном падеже как абсолютные обстоятельства.

Comment: А где тут существительные в предложном падеже? «Газону», «столу», «ветру» — это дательный падеж. Предложный падеж употребляется только с предлогами _в, на, при, о._

Comment: Ладно, всё-таки дательный, а не местный. Но это сути не меняет. Покажите мне, где написано, что существительные с предлогами (в частности, по ...у) могут выступать только обстоятельствами, и дискуссия будет исчерпана.

Comment: Мы от обсуждения «по ветру» перешли к «по столу», «по газону» и т.п. Получается бесконечная дискуссия. Я считаю, что дополнение является объектом, на который направлено действие глагола. В данном случае на ветер никакого воздействия не оказывается, ни прямо, ни косвенно. [Определить] «по ветру» — это обстоятельство образа действия.

Comment: Хотелось бы добавить, что в примере с газоном смысл следующий: *Он шёл по газону и топтал его.* Тоже обстоятельство?

Comment: oleedd, хороший пример, мне нравится. Здесь дополнение: шел  (по чему?).  Влияют однородные отношения с местоимением "его".   В каждом конкретном предложении или объект определяет место действия (обстоятельство), или объект  взаимодействует с глаголом (дополнение).  ГАЗОН, -а; м. [франц. gazon] Площадка, участок в саду, парке, на бульваре и т.п., засеянный травой, обычно коротко и ровно подстриженной; трава на такой площадке, участке. В одном случае у нас площадка, а в другом – трава на площадке.

Answer (score 0):

> Предлоги, союзы и частицы обычно не имеют на себе самостоятельного
> ударения и примыкают к самостоятельным частям речи: ***за горо́й, не
> была́, оте́ц бы, придёт ли, сади́сь же.*** В некоторых случаях ударение
> переходит на предлог: ***по́д гору, на́ пол, за́ ночь.*** Таким образом,
> самостоятельные и служебные слова имеют одно словесное ударение,
> составляя единое по звучанию фонетическое слово.
> ...
> .1. Перенос ударения на предлоги на, за, под, по, из, без возможен, если в предложении после существительного нет поясняющих его слов:
> ...
>
> .3) в сочетаниях с предлогом по (с дательным падежом) – при
> значении этого предлога «на поверхности, в пределах» (о движении),
> например: ***ходить по́ полу, по́ полю, по́ двору, гулять по́ лесу,
> летать по́ небу, плавать по́ морю, рассыпаться по́ полу, по́ лесу***.
>
> При других значениях этих предлогов переноса ударения может не
> происходить, например:
> ... 
> в) ***тоска по мо́рю, по не́бу, судить по
> двору́, по ле́су, каждому досталось по по́лю***.
>
> Переноса ударения обычно не происходит, если во фразе за
> существительным следует поясняющее его слово или слова (подчиненные
> ему или связанные с ним сочинительной связью), например:
>
> ...
>
> в) ***по двору́ гостиницы, по сне́гу и льду Финского залива, по мо́рю
> Лаптевых***.
>
> [[Розенталь Д.Э. и др. Справочник]](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/74.htm)

В предложении *«Отправил пёрышко в полёт по ветру»* слово «ветру» стоит в дательном падеже и после него нет поясняющего слова.

Теперь нужно разобраться, означает ли в приведённом предложении предлог «по» «на поверхности, в пределах».

На мой взгляд, «по» тут может значить:

> 8. Употребляется при обозначении предмета, посредством которого или при помощи которого совершается действие.
>    *Отправить по почте. Говорить
>    по телефону. Передать по радио. Ориентироваться по компасу. Он
>    раскрыл книгу и начал читать по ней молитвы.* Кузьмин, Круг царя
>    Соломона.
>
> [Малый академический словарь под редакцией Евгеньевой]

«Отправил пёрышко в полёт ***посредством*** ветра»

Может ещё быть:

> 5. Употребляется при обозначении предмета, следуя направлению которого совершается действие.
>    Гладить по шерсти. Идти по ветру. Идти по
>    следу зверя. Плыть по течению. Во время полета снаряда все
>    поворачивают головы по звуку, словно видят летящий снаряд.
>    Катаев,
>    Почти дневник.
>
> [Малый академический словарь под редакцией Евгеньевой]

«Отправил пёрышко в полёт ***по направлению*** ветра»

Но, на мой взгляд, это не подходит. Поскольку пёрышко на было просто брошено по направлению ветра, а ветер был использован как инструмент, то посредством чего, при помощи чего будет осуществляться движение пёрышка.

Так или иначе правило Розенталя *«при значении этого предлога „на поверхности, в пределах“ (о движении)»* тут не подходит.

Варианты *«Отправил пёрышко в полёт **на поверхности** ветра»* или *«Отправил пёрышко в полёт **в пределах** ветра»* — не имеют смысла.

*«Ходить по́ полю»* — *«Ходить **на поверхности** поля»* — имеет смысл, а *«Отправил пёрышко в полёт **на поверхности** ветра»* — смысла не имеет, у ветра нет поверхности.

Таким образом? формально причин для переноса ударения на предлог нет.

---

С другой стороны люди могут воспринимать ветер, как некий поток у которого есть поверхность и им может казаться, что они как бы кладут пёрышко на поверхность этого потока, и он его несёт.

Кроме того, правило Розенталя не жёсткое: он пишет *«1. Перенос ударения на предлоги *на, за, под, по, из, без* **возможен**…»* и *«Переноса ударения **обычно** не происходит…»*.

Слова «возможен» и «обычно» означают, что нет твёрдой уверенности в том, что будет именно так.