# Ударить ногой. Как или чем?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Как ударить? Ногой.
Чем ударить? Ногой.*

Почему допустим один и тот же ответ на два разных вопроса?

Comment: А вы умеете задавать вопросы. Вопрос о вопросах это первое с чем надо определиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вкратце, то есть вопросы морфологические, а есть синтаксические, и они не обязаны совпадать. А теперь подробнее.

В русском языке все вопросы делятся на падежно-ориентированные группы вопросов:

1. Каков, Каковому, Каковым, ...
2. Какой, Какого, Какому, Каким, О каком, ...
3. Чей, Чьего, Чьему, ...
4. Что, Чего, Чему, ...
5. итд
   ...

Отдельно стоит группа падежно-неориентированных вопросов:
Как, Каким образом, Почему, Куда, Где, ...

Слово не может отвечать на **два разных вопроса** из одной подгруппы. Поскольку падеж уже содержится внутри слова (в виде окончания). Либо же диктуется логикой предложения (так как винительный и родительный падежы совпадают в окончаниях) . В английском языке слово легко может отвечать сразу на несколько вопросов из одной падежной группы, так как в нем нету падежей.

И в русском, и в английском слово может отвечать на два разных вопроса из разных падежных подгрупп.
Например, в словосочетании **Карандаш Васи**, существительное Васи отвечает аж на три разных вопроса, а иногда и на 4-й:

```
Кого карандаш? - Карандаш Васи.
Какой карандаш? - Карандаш Васи.
Который карандаш? - Карандаш Васи.

Чей карандаш? - Карандаш Васин.
Какой карандаш? - Карандаш Васин.
Который карандаш? - Карандаш Васин.
```

Пример из английского, в котором слово отвечает на два разных вопроса из одной падежной группы:

```
He was a doctor.
Он был врачом (кем?).
Он был врач (кто?).
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы перемудрили. На вопросы *чей? чья? чьё? чьи?* отвечают **притяжательные** прилагательные: *карандаш* (чей?) *Васи**н*** (Танин мяч, Серёжины коньки).

Comment: Спасибо, поправил. Но, согласитесь, что "его карандаш" отвечает и на "чей карандаш?" и на "кого карандаш?". Ведь притяжательного егоный не существует.

Comment: **Его** 1. род. и вин. п. от личных местоимений *он* и *оно*. [Его (кого?) терзали смутные сомнения.] 2. В значении притяжательного местоимения: принадлежащий ему. *Его* (чья?) *семья. Его* (чьи?) *вещи.* (http://endic.ru/academic/Ego-4214.html)

Comment: Очередной п****ц...

Answer (score 0):

Давно известно, что иногда дополнение может отвечать на вопросы обстоятельства и наоборот. См. вопрос [Отправить пёрышко в полёт по́ ветру или по ве́тру?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467139)

Так же и в следующих примерах:
*Где / на чём? На столе.

Ехал как / на чём? На автобусе.

Защищался как/чем? Мечом.

Ходить где / по чему? По газону.*

Более точный ответ на вопрос "как ударить?" — "с ноги".